# How to Find Path to a Certain Object Without Knowing Its Position in a Grid Based Video Game?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, path-finding, a-star

I´m in the middle of the development of a personal project . In this video game there is a grid based movement , creation and pathfinding system . Previously , I have used A* pathfinding in order to make certain characters move towards a certain known position .

But now I have encountereda big question . There is a character in my game that has to go to a certain kind of object , but this character doesn´t know the exact coordinate of such object . The easiest way of doing this would be to actually know the coordinates of those objects , calculate which one is the nearest one and use A* pathfinding in order to get to that point , but that aproach seems really rigged and not dynamic enough for the type of game I´m making.

So I would like to know if there is some pathfinding algorithm that searches around a certain point (the location of the character that is using that algorithm) , like in a radial way , and keeps searching until it finds the object type that is looking for and returns the path to that certain object.

Comment: Like FirstStep said use Dijkstra, but if you already got A* implemented set heuristic to 0 and you basically got Dijkstra.

Comment: And if your edges are all equal weight, you can use Breadth First Search, which is simpler and faster than Dijkstra's Algorithm. (I have a [tutorial](http://www.redblobgames.com/pathfinding/a-star/introduction.html) that shows Breadth First Search — you'll modify the Early Exit line to stop when you get the right object instead of a specific location)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look up for Dijkstra's Algorithm. It basically covers the whole graph before calculating the shortest path to a destination, unlike A* which goes towards the destination upfront. In other words, Dijkstra finds *ALL* the paths to All Nodes from a source, but then choose a destination and its shortest path or least cost. There is a nice GIF on Wiki illustrates what I mean here: [Click](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) and look up A* on Wiki to see its GIF and understand this comparison.

How Dijkstra's Algorithm approach the shortest path to a destination:
[image]

How A* Algorithm approach the shortest path to a destination:

[image]